# Wordpress проблема c CCF(carbon custom fields) не могу вывести значения комплексных полей SOS

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

я регаю комплексные поля

```
add_action('carbon_fields_register_fields','reg_composition_fields');
function reg_composition_fields(){
    Container::make( 'post_meta', 'О продукте' )
    ->where( 'post_type', '=', 'goods_post_type' )
    ->add_fields( array(
        Field::make( 'complex', 'crb_product_composition' )
            ->add_fields(array(
                Field::make( 'text', 'crb_product_composition_el', 'Элемент состава' )
            )),
    ))->add_fields(array(
        Field::make('text', 'crb_product_info_calories','Энергетическая ценность'),
        Field::make('text', 'crb_product_info_save','Условия хранения'),
        Field::make('text', 'crb_product_info_time','Срок годности'),
        Field::make('text', 'crb_product_info_way','Способ приготовления'),
    ));
}
```

поля кторые не входят в комплекс выводятся как должны. вывожу их с помощью функции:

```
carbon_get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'crb_product_info_calories');
```

но когда я пытаюсь вывести комплексные поля , которые 'crb_product_composition',
выводит пустой массив.
вывожу с помощью той же функции.

```
 carbon_get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'crb_product_composition','complex');
```

в чем может быть проблема ?
возможно из-за этой строки ?

```
->where( 'post_type', '=', 'goods_post_type' )
```

да и еще. делаю дебаг функции которая выводит все поля которые есть у записи

```
debug(get_post_custom(get_the_ID()));
```

воводит вот это:

```
Array
(
    [_edit_last] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [_edit_lock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1550759823:1
        )

    [_thumbnail_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 131
        )

    [_wp_old_slug] => Array
        (
            [0] => %d1%85%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9
        )

    [_crb_product_composition|||0|value] => Array
        (
            [0] => _
        )

    [_crb_product_composition|||1|value] => Array
        (
            [0] => _
        )

    [_crb_product_composition|||2|value] => Array
        (
            [0] => _
        )

    [_crb_product_composition|crb_product_composition_el|0|0|value] => Array
        (
            [0] => Шаурма
        )

    [_crb_product_composition|crb_product_composition_el|1|0|value] => Array
        (
            [0] => Соль
        )

    [_crb_product_composition|crb_product_composition_el|2|0|value] => Array
        (
            [0] => насвай
        )

    [_crb_product_info_calories] => Array
        (
            [0] => куцкуц
        )

    [_crb_product_info_save] => Array
        (
            [0] => куцк
        )

    [_crb_product_info_time] => Array
        (
            [0] => цукуц
        )

    [_crb_product_info_way] => Array
        (
            [0] => уцкуцк
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос. 3-й аргумент функции `('complex')` не нужен `carbon_get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'crb_product_composition','complex');`